# What is this plant? (sweet potato?)

Tags: identification, tomatoes, sweet-potato

A long while ago, I planted what I'm pretty sure was the head of a sweet potato that started growing.

The plant is still small but growing, and it has some small fruit-beginning (all green, but one which is red), but it really doesn't seems like it's going to be a sweet potato or something similar. It looks more like a tiny cherry tomato.

So, is it a sweet potato plant, or something else jumped into my pot? If so, what it is?

[image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

Comment: Potato and tomato are family, but be careful the fruits of potato plants are poisonous. [Solanaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanaceae)

Comment: So since their are relatives, it still can be the potato, and it will take that form in a later stage? Or this fruit is something else and not going to develop to a sweet potato?

Comment: Note both tomatoes and potatoes are of Genus `Solanum` (so not just the family). In any case potatoes could flowers and produce fruits. Are you in Europe? To me it seems just a weed of Solanum genus. Do no eat it. Note: Sweet potatoes are of a completely different family (and different flowers). this is not a sweet potato.

Comment: I live in Israel, and I didn't planned eating it, was just curios about what it is actually! Thanks!

Comment: Sweet potatoes are completely different than potatoes.  Good call Giacomo.

Comment: A potato it's definitely not, but it doesn't look like a sweet potato which is what I planted.

Comment: I am pretty sure Brenn is correct.  Deadly Nightshade.  Same family as potatoes, tomatoes, egg plant and peppers.

Comment: @stormy I am pretty sure deadly nighthade does not have white flowers.   It does strike me as being of the nighshade family though. (https://first-nature.com/flowers/atropa-belladonna.php describes purple flowers for the Deadly Nighshade).  I still would not eat any part of the plant unless fully identified),  Its not an Eggplant, and I doubt its a tomato.

Comment: I believe you are right.  I thought I knew deadly nightshade better than that.

Comment: It definitely looks like a Solanum berry of some kind (but yes, not a tomato, potato or eggplant). I'm growing Solanum nigrum (Otricoli Orange berry and Chichiquelite) and it looks similar. Wonderberries look similar, too, but they'd probably have a lot more and duller fruit with no red. It's likely Solanum nigrum as I think the answerer meant. Where did you get your sweet potatoes and soil? Do those places sell any Solanum berries that look like this? If so, that might explain how it got there, but I wouldn't eat it anyway, just in case. It could be a toxic plant from a wild weed seed.

Comment: What confuses me is how you planted a root-type start to get this plant. They should grow from seed. Perhaps that died and a stray seed grew in its spot.

Comment: @Shule I bought the sweet potato on the market, and just planted the part of it that started growing - so weird!!

Answer (score 2):

It's common nightshade. It's not considered an edible, in fact, it's toxic.

Comment: It indeed looks pretty similar, can you please elaborate more about it? How did it grew there? Where can it arrive from?

Comment: Do you mean Solanum nigrum? There are edible varieties of Solanum nigrum (when ripe only), but you'd want to be careful with a wild kind, since they could be either.

Comment: I do I believe that it looks like a berry in the Solanum genus, though, whether or not it's that specific one. There are different species that look pretty similar.

Comment: Solanum ptychanthum is called Common Nightshade. Is that what you mean? Solanum americanum?